# Create Button Dynamically - JQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How to create the button dynamically using jQuertMobile.

Answer (score 10):

Very simple:

First create a button HTML JQuery element by:

```
var button = $("<button>My Button</button>");
```

Next, inject the button wherever you want it to be in the page:

```
$("#my_button_div").append(button);
```

And finally run the button() JQuery Mobile command on the button:

```
button.button();
```

You should have a functional and JQM styled button in your page by now.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: Now it's done with an event you trigger.

```
.trigger('create')
```

Details and up-to-date description "How do I make JQM work with content I add to DOM?" is here: http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/faq.html

Create it and then call `page()` on the element. It will apply all plugins and styles from jquery mobile to any element you create.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
var button = $("<button>My Button</button>");
$("#my_button_div").append(button).trigger('create');
```

here example: [jquery mobile create grid dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675629/jquery-mobile-create-grid-type-buttons-dynamically/15155980#15155980)

Answer (score 0):

Above link is broken and the solution doesn't work for me.

The following code does not work:

```
$(this.el).append("<button id='add2' data-role='button'>Add list item</button>");

$('#add2').page();
```

The button is added and works perfectly without calling `$('#add2').page();` but it has no JQuery Mobile styling. Calling `.page()` is therefore not a working fix for applying the styling after adding the button to the DOM.