# jquery mobile: create grid type buttons dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I want to create a jquery mobile grid consists of buttons with 'onclick' or 'href' functionality. The number of buttons should be created dynamically during runtime. For example, This block of code should work like a library index. on clicking a library button, it should show the 'book names' in a grid of buttons, and on clicking the buttons of book names, it should show another grid of buttons which consists of 'chapter numbers' in the book which will be  created dynamically upon book selection. My static html code for creating the grid is,

```
<div class="ui-grid-d" id="book_chooser">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><button class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:30px">Book A</button></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><button class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:30px">Book B</button></div>
        <div class="ui-block-c"><button class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:30px">Book C</button></div> 
        <div class="ui-block-d"><button class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:30px">Book D</button></div>
        <div class="ui-block-e"><button class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:30px">Book E</button></div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><button class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:30px">Book A</button></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><button class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:30px">Book B</button></div>
        <div class="ui-block-c"><button class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:30px">Book C</button></div> 
        <div class="ui-block-d"><button class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:30px">Book D</button></div>
        <div class="ui-block-e"><button class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:30px">Book E</button></div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><button class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:30px">Book A</button></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><button class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:30px">Book B</button></div>
        <div class="ui-block-c"><button class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:30px">Book C</button></div> 
        <div class="ui-block-d"><button class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:30px">Book D</button></div>
        <div class="ui-block-e"><button class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:30px">Book E</button></div>
```

Need this grid of buttons should to be created dynamically on run time based on the number of books.

I'm using jquery, javascript and html5 with phonegap plugin.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need append elements and then call trigger('create') for each element, more easy with example:

```
function redrawGrid(num){

    $('#book_chooser').html(''); //clean grid
    for (var i = 0, class_div = "a"; i < num; i++) {

        var d = '<div class="ui-block-'+class_div+'"> \
                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:70px"> \
                        <small>dia '+ (i+1) +'</small> \
                        <button type="submit" data-theme="a" data-icon="plus">Book</button> \
                    </div> \
                </div>';

        $('#book_chooser').append(d).trigger('create'); 

        switch(class_div){ //change class of ui-block
            case 'a' : class_div= "b"; break;
            case 'b' : class_div= "a";break;
        }
    };
}
```

I hope that work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

First create a button HTML JQuery element by:

```
var button = $("<button>My Button</button>");
```

Next, inject the button wherever you want it to be in the page:

```
$("#my_button_div").append(button);
```

And finally run the button() JQuery Mobile command on the button:

```
button.button();
```

You should have a functional and JQM styled button in your page by now.